# connection to mysql database using config.php file not working

Tags: php, mysql, config

I have a php file that looks like this:

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); // put the *FULL* path to the file.

    $values = $_POST;

    foreach ($values as &$value) {
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }

    $sq1="INSERT INTO applicant (app_trn,app_file_id)

    VALUES
    ('$values[app_trn]','$values[app_file_id]')";

    ?>
```

and this Is my config.php file:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('lms', $link);
?>
```

How ever when It is not working I cant seem to find the problem, Im a bit fresh to php and mysql so could you please oversea this and see if i have any errors

Comment: What about it isn't working?  Do you get an error?

Comment: enable error reporting while working; this would give you a notice for sure: `$values[app_trn]` and maybe you will find other problems also

Comment: @LawrenceCherone They're escaped as references. note the `&$values`.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, he's changed the value of the original array by reference.

Comment: My main problem is with connecting to the database, is the config file ok, also is the other php file ok connection wise?

Comment: in the other file you are not running the query, you need a call to `mysql_query`; about the config file: there's nothing wrong about it, if the connection doesn't work you should get the message you set and you just need to update the credentials

Comment: yes that was actually the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you code doesn't suppose to do anything, is it possible you forgot to send the query to mysql? if so... :

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($sq1);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using array variables in a doube-quotes-enclosed string the variable needs to be enclosed in curly brackets:

```
$sq1="INSERT INTO applicant (app_trn,app_file_id)

VALUES
('{$values['app_trn']}','{$values['app_file_id']}')";
```

Also, the index of the array element should be enclosed in single-quotes in these cases.

E.g. `$values['app_trn']` rather than `$values[app_trn]`.

Comment: The unquoted array keys (however poor a practice) are actually valid inside double quoted strings without wrapping in `{}`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Ok thanks for that But my main problem is connecting to the database